# Error Pycharm (Run)

Tags: python, pycharm

Hola llevo mucho utilizando **pycharm** actualmente no puedo utilizar el **apartado de ejecución de programas**

**Este es mi codigo**

```
#Modulos
from vidstream import AudioSender
from vidstream import AudioReceiver
import os
import socket
import threading
import time
os.system("cls")


#Modulos de error

try:
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    IP = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

    receiver = AudioReceiver(IP, 9999)
    receiver_thread = threading.Thread(target=receiver.start_server)

    IP_AUT = "192.168.1.19"
    sender = AudioSender(IP_AUT, 8888)
    sender_thread = threading.Thread(target=sender.start_stream)

    receiver_thread.start()
    sender_thread.start()

except:
    print("Posibles Errores:")
    print("Error al Obtener Dirección de IP")
    print("Envianos captura de tu problema por nuestros contactos")
    print("Discord = PingüiMaya14#2055")
    print("Instagram = pinguimaya14")
    print("\n Tienes 20 segundos para tomar captura")
    time.sleep(20)



    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 40, in init numpy.random.bit_generator
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\secrets.py", line 20, in <module>
    from random import SystemRandom
  File "D:\USER\Desktop\pingüi_pruebas\random.py", line 6, in <module>
    number = number.randint(10,20)
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/USER/Desktop/pingüi_pruebas/Audio Chat/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vidstream import AudioSender
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vidstream\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vidstream.streaming import StreamingServer
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vidstream\streaming.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Otro de los errores es que se me ejecuta otro programa y no el que puse que se me ejecutara en Pycharm**

Siempre que he intentado crear un programa utilizando modulos me da dicho error **PD: No estoy utilizando ninguna libreria de las que aparecen ahí, tambien ya comprobe que estoy ejecutando el archivo correcto, Tambien ya probe usando `pip install -U numpy`**, `pip install numpy==1.19.3`

Agradecería de antemano su ayuda

Comment: Podrías poner el mensaje de error completo por favor? Lo que pusiste en la pregunta es la ubicación del error, no el error en si.

Comment: Si bien no utilizas las librerias mencionadas en el mensaje de error, si las utilizan los modulos que estás usando en tu programa. Por lo que, implicita e internamente, las estás usando.

Comment: Hola dante claro ahorita lo hago

Comment: Estube viendo el mensaje de error y parece que uno de tus errores está en el script random.py. Podrías agregar su código a la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Si en un momento lo agrego

Comment: Tengo cosas que decir. Primero, me parece raro que en tu archivo random.py, la linea 6 no es lo que afirma el error. NO es number=number...

Comment: Segundo, en esta linea `sender_thread = threading.Thread(target=sender.start_stream())` quitale los parentesis a start_stream, ya que si no la función se ejecuta. Lo que buscas es pasarle el objeto función al thread.

Comment: Lo probaste sin los parentesis a ver si de causalidad solucionó el problema?

Comment: Si, lo probe sin eso, lo segundo fue un error de mano, pero siempre pycharm me ha dado ese error desde hace poco, podría ser actualización ?

Comment: No se nada de Pycharm por desgracia, pero es posible que segun [esta pregunta](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010057200-ImportError-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import) que tu versión de numpy sea incompatible con tu versión de pycharm, probaste con hacer lo que te dicen en esta pregunta?

Comment: Lo intentaré y te digo

Comment: Lamentablemente no funciono, intentaré actualizar pycharm y si funciona te digo para que pongas la respuesta así verificarla

Comment: No funciono : (

Comment: Que mala suerte :c Entonces no se que hacer...

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a votar esta pregunta para ver si alguien mas puede contestarla, ya que necesito arreglar ese problema por favor : )

Comment: Por supuesto, ya voto!

Comment: Gracias !!!!!!!

Comment: De nada c: Suerte con tu problema!

Comment: Intentaste esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import/55886600#55886600 ? osea `pip uninstall numpy` hasta que no quede nada

Comment: Hola @Emeeus lamentablemente no funciono, primero lo desintale y luego instale la nueva version luego de eso no funciono luego lo volvi a desinstalar e instalé la 1.19.3, y no funciono de ninguna de las maneras

Comment: Pero intentaste desintalando varias veces seguidas?

Comment: Si @Emeeus, pero no funciono

Comment: Buenas, me parece que estas interpretando mal el error, no es una libreria... es un error de sintaxis posiblemente. Puedes agregar mas detalle del codigo en si?

Comment: Hola ese es el codigo completo pero no es un error de sintaxis ya ni nada que ver ya que ese codigo me da en todos los scripts con un librerias que utlizan de dichas librerías,

Answer (score 5):

Estoy viendo dos cosas:

En la lista de errores hay una llamada a `D:\USER\Desktop\pingüi_pruebas\random.py`a través de `numpy` cuando intenta importar `random`.

`numpy` es una dependencia de una dependencia de `vidstream`, por lo que el error de importación provoca una cascada.

Espero que tengas `numpy` instalado.

Elucubro que cambiando el nombre del archivo `D:\USER\Desktop\pingüi_pruebas\random.py` a uno que no se solape con ninguna libreria de python, como `pingüi_random.py` arreglarás este problema y muchos otros al intentar ejecutar código desde pycharm.

Comprueba también que los nombres de tus archivos de python en la carpeta `D:\USER\Desktop\pingüi_pruebas` no se solapen con ninguna otra librería.

Comment: +1 no se como no pensé en eso antes!

Comment: Hola, tienes razon, claro numpy lo tengo instalado pero el error de vidstream es un error ya solucionado que es ejecutarlo en otra IDLE, pero intentaré probar lo que me dices de random.py

Comment: @Iván Uría - Eh cambiado el nombre a algunos archivos que tenian relacion ahora mi problema es otro aparte el de numpy que me ejecuta otro programa en vez de el que yo quiero (ya configuré el que quiero pero igual )

Comment: Si necesitas ayuda vas a tener que ampliar información o, si has abierto una nueva pregunta, enlaza aquí para que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo,

Comment: Esa es toda la información, necesito de tu ayuda por favor

Comment: ¿Has cambiado el nombre de D:\USER\Desktop\pingüi_pruebas\random.py? Si es ese el caso el traceback del error tiene que haber cambiado, ya no podría dar `File "C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\secrets.py", line 20, in <module>
    from random import SystemRandom
  File "D:\USER\Desktop\pingüi_pruebas\random.py", line 6, in <module>
    number = number.randint(10,20)
NameError: name 'number' is not defined`

Comment: Hola si ya modifique random.py por randompingui.py pero aun me da el error numpy yo pensé que era lo mismo que random al final seguía el error

Comment: Hola, lo que digo es que el error tiene que ser otro si has cambiado el nombre. Puede seguir dando error numpy, pero será diferente.